# the same assembly flagged as not available and available in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I'm trying to troubleshoot a public property in  ASP.NET code-behind being flagged as inaccessible on the ASPX html markup page.

```
var s = <%=foo%>
```

`Foo` is inaccessible although declared `Public` in code-behind.

Another object declaration on the page may provide a clue, so I'm asking about it here as a separate isolated question:

```
Private WithEvents MyGizmo as Gizmo
```

When I hover over "Gizmo", which is underlined in red, Visual Studio displays this popup:

```
Class MyAssemblyName.Gizmo
   MyAssemblyName -- Not Available
   MyAssemblyName -- Available
```

What does it mean when Visual Studio 2015 reports the same assembly as being both available and not available? What condition would cause that?

VS has a suggested fix: Import **MyAssemblyName**.

If it helps, this is a legacy website from circa 2003 which has been "upgraded" over the years through several generations of Visual Studio and IIS.

Its type is **Class Library**.

Comment: Are the assembly versions the same?  It might do that for the same assembly if it's one version one place and another elsewhere.  Which can definitely happen with old 'upgraded' projects.

Comment: I checked for more than one copy of the DLL. There was a "backup" folder that did have an older version. I moved it and that specific error went away. Thanks.   The property being inaccessible is still a mystery.

Comment: Did you convert a Web Site project to a WebApplication project? Did you have a folder named APP_CODE inside a WebApplication project?

Comment: @Steve: I'm not sure of the history since I'm coming onto this project long after the original coders, who are no longer here.  There is a folder named App_Code but with nothing in it. Should all of the code-behind classes be moved  there?

Comment: No in case of a WebApplication you should remove anything inside that APP_CODE folder and also remove or rename it. If you look at your Object Browser window did you see two namespaces for MyAssemblyName? I had this problem because manually converting the WebSite (and not following [the tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx)) resulted in a double namespace.